# When does Volterra equation have a log-convex solution?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Consider the following linear Volterra equation for $x(\cdot)$:

$x(t)=1-\int_0^t a(t-s)x(s)ds, \qquad t\ge 0.$

The question is: what are the most general assumptions on $a(\cdot)$ for the solution to be log-convex. I think it has been shown for $a$ being completely monotone (plus some integrability condition). Is there anything better?